# MSProject/Excel VBA Loop through 'Flag' columns, how?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement, ms-project

Hopefully an easy one.  In Excel VBA, I'd like to be able to loop through the custom flag columns in a MSProject file I have open.

In pseudo

```
For i = 1 to 20
If task.flagi then ....
```

Ho do I write the 'flagi' in code?

Thanks,

Jon C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Set task = ActiveProject.Tasks.Add("Test Task")
Dim Index As Integer
For Index = 1 To 20
    Dim fieldName As String
    fieldName = "Flag" & Index

    Dim fieldValue
    fieldValue = task.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant(fieldName))
    '
    ' Your code here
    '
Next
```

You could also use the `pjField` constants directly to access the fields (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff867782.aspx), although they are slightly harder to work with (for example they are not in the numeric order you'd expect!)

Comment: Makes sense but I must be off the mark somewhere.

Using: